# JS Function restrict type of arguments

Tags: javascript

Let's say i have a range() function that returns an array of numbers in a range, how can i make sure that this function only accepts numbers as arguments?. Is it correct to throw an error like new Error('input must be a number')?. Thanks in advance.

```js
function range(from, to, step = 1) {
    if (!to) {
        to = from;
        from = 0;
    }
    let result = []
    for (let i = from; i < to; i += step) {
        result.push(i)
    }
    return result
}

const rango1 = range(5);    // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
const rango2 = range(2, 8); // [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
const rango3 = range(3, 12, 2); //[3, 5, 7, 9, 11]

console.log(rango1)
console.log(rango2)
console.log(rango3)

console.log(range('string')) // throw Error instead []
```

Comment: From is a reserved word in js. Please consider using a different variable name?

Comment: @evolutionxbox ok, we can call it 'start' maybe

Comment: You literally have included the solution in your title.  `typeof x` returns "number" if `x` is a number.  You could also use `Number.parseInt(x)` to make it a little more flexible

Comment: `arguments.forEach(i => typeof i !== "Number" && throw new Error("only numbers are allowed"))`

Comment: @Tibrogargan my question is about understanding error handling in JS, to give a feedback to any dev that want to use this function

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought it was about your code.  Going to have vote to close this as too broad.

Comment: @Tibrogargan What makes this question too broad?

Comment: @Spectric Literally this: " my question is about understanding error handling in JS, to give a feedback to any dev that want to use this function".  That's a very broad question.

Comment: @evolutionxbox `from` is not a reserved word

Comment: If you need typisation, I'd recommend to use Typsescript, checking for the parameter types in JS is something highly non-idiomatic for this language.

Comment: I think the answer is depends on what your function is for. If it's for your own code, then probably throwing error would be unnecessary, `return null` would probably be a petter choice. If it's for a library, then yes, throwing error would be appropriate.

Comment: @Bergi huh. I could’ve sworn it was.